# My post on a Nemesis thread

Tags: support, specific-question, answers

I was wondering why My post was deleted in the question regarding the nest destruction
I think it was an alternative / question following the same line of the idea.

[Does depressurising The Nest kill the eggs?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54135/does-depressurising-the-nest-kill-the-eggs/56608#56608)

Here`s a screenshot
[image]

I tried contacting the users who deleted it but even with the provided email on one of them My emails kept bouncing back.  Any help please ?

Comment: You posted a question as an answer. That is not how SE works. The question should have been posted as a question (as explicitly stated in the comments).

Answer (score 14):

With all due respect, did you read the comments that were posted?

> However, please note that we're not a regular discussion forum, but rather a focused Q&A site. If you have a new question, please use the [Ask Question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button rather than posting an answer to an existing question.

Stack Exchange runs on a model of [no chit-chat](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour). Your post would be perfectly fine as a new question, but should not be posted as an "answer" to a different question *as it isn't an answer to the question*.

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, not a system of post threads like most forums and social media. You posted a new question as an answer to the question - it wasn't an answer so it was deleted.

If you want to ask a new question, you hit the ask question button, if you want to reference another question that inspired your new question, you can add a link to that original question in your new question, like I did in my question [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43749/what-happens-if-a-double-faced-card-that-is-copying-a-different-double-faced-car).

Comment: I understand the posting now, but like I said, My question was in the same line of Idea and I was submitting a new idea through the question.

Comment: @LordRamiro If your intention is to have the original question expanded, then **comment** on the original question to suggest that the original poster make the edit. But really, in most cases, the new question should be posted as a new question.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson The OP won't have been able to comment on the question due to not having 50 rep - but that's no reason for posting answer-comments.

Comment: Ah, right. The solution then is to gain rep, which often leads to finding out more about how the site works, to boot.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson which brings us back to his best choice being asking a related question (which I'd say is still the better choice over asking for the original question to be changed) earning him the rep he needs because it is a decent question to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Your "answer" was deleted because it did not provide an answer to the question. For more information, please see [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) If you want to know how to write a good answer, please see: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer